# Select which Webcam to use in OpenCV

Tags: c++, video, opencv, selection, webcam

I have a built in webcam (HP) and an USB webcam. Whenever I use webcams in OpenCV, the built in webcam is used. However I want use the USB webcam. I tried disabling the built in webcam and even uninstalling the drivers, but after doing that, I get a message saying that no webcams were detected, even though the USB webcam is connected. How can I use the USB webcam instead of the built in webcam? I have searched the net top to bottom and have found no fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command [`CaptureFromCAM`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromcam) accepts an integer as its only argument which specifies the device number to use. Change this number and it will use a different device.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but have you any idea how to make it work in JavaCV? Because I do not know where to find CaptureFromCAM in JavaCV.

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used that library. However if it's anything like the regular API, you need to import the `highgui` portion (package) of the library, that's where this functionality lives.

Comment: @Chris - could you be a bit more specific as to what do you mean by "Change this number"? What number should one use?

Comment: @YePhIcK it's arbitrary. It starts from 0, indicating the first device it found, and increments from there.

Comment: I should probably be more specific with my question - how do I know which number to use? How do I get that from my user - which camera does he want to use? Should I just blindly present a choice of numbers 1 through, say, 5? Or is there a better way to do it (I hope)?

Comment: Reading OpenCV code (cap.cpp) I see that 0-99 is used to index the device and then I can append a "domain" (a type of interface/driver to use) to it. While I clearly see how one would choose the second number (the domain) I'm not as clear on the index of the camera device. It would seem that there **was** a way to do it by calling `cvcamGetCamerasCount( );` but that function is removed from OpenCV :(

Comment: @YePhIcK You blindly choose one, see if that's the right one, and if it's not, move on to the next number. There is no sanity or reason behind the numbering (except that they're adjacent and start at 0).

Comment: That makes me super-curious... the very first time I ran my program on a laptop (which had a built-in and an attached camera) I had a dialog pop-up to chose a camera (maybe it was a Windows dialog and not OpenCV?). That dialog has never popped up again. Ever. And when I now run the same program on my desktop with 2 attached cameras I don't get the dialog box either Do you have any idea if there's a way to "bring back the dialog"?